# The operator - under defined for the arguement type(s) EditText, int

Tags: eclipse, sqlite, undefined

Im trying to create an activity which adds name, age, and maxhr to sqlite and will be displayed in a listview in Eclipse. name and age is an input text. Maxhr is age(input text)  minus 220. But im getting "The operator - under defined for the arguement type(s) EditText, int" error. I can't seem to find the answer for this error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
package com.heartrate.monitoring.activities;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.heartratemonitoringapp.R;
import com.heartrate.monitoring.dao.UserDAO;
import com.heartrate.monitoring.model.User;

public class AddUserActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    public static final String TAG = "AddUserActivity";

    private EditText mTxtName;
    private EditText mTxtAge;
    private Button mBtnAdd;

    private UserDAO mUserDao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_user);
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        initViews();

        this.mUserDao = new UserDAO(this);
    }

    private void initViews() {
        this.mTxtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_name);
        this.mTxtAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_age);
        this.mBtnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);

        this.mBtnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_add:
            Editable name = mTxtName.getText();
            Editable age = mTxtAge.getText();

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(name) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(age)){
                // add the user to database
                double mhr;
                double maxhr;
                mhr = Double.parseDouble(mTxtAge.getText().toString());;
                maxhr = mhr - 220;
                User createdUser = mUserDao.createUser(
                        name.toString(), age.toString(),
                        maxhr.toString());

                Log.d(TAG, "added user : "+ createdUser.getName());
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.putExtra(ListUserActivity.EXTRA_ADDED_USER, createdUser);
                setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.user_created_successfully, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.empty_fields_message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mUserDao.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `;` on this line: `mhr = Double.parseDouble(mTxtAge.getText().toString());;`

Comment: sorry about that. Now im having cannot invoke to String() on primitive type double in maxhr.toString());

Comment: @AlxMnza `maxhr` is of type primitive `double`. you cannot use `toString()` as it's not an `Object`.

Comment: how can i fix this? sorry im new in java